# Vb. net, input inside textbox

Tags: vb.net

i can't use Backspace button in the keyboard in changing or editing what is being inputted by the user when he/she commits mistake inputting the series of integers...help me please...

```
Private Sub tbx3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tbx3.KeyPress
    If CInt(Val(e.KeyChar)) = 8 Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim allowedchar As String = "1234567890"
    If Not (allowedchar.Contains(e.KeyChar)) Then
        e.KeyChar = CChar(e.KeyChar)

        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: so you only want to input integers?

Comment: yes sir,because it is a Purchase Order Number so I made some trappings so that the user would not be confuse and would not complain.

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Comment: yes sir but it's just the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) _
          Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
        e.Handled = True
End If
If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        e.Handled = False
End If
```